# JFrame not displaying in multiple screens when we setUndecorated(true)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, graphics2d

I am working on a use case where an undecorated `JFrame` needs to span across all the available displays. When i use regular `JFrame` with `setSize` i can see the `JFrame` stretching as per the dimensions given. The same `JFrame`, when we `setUndecorated(true)`, it is not displaying.

The below code fragment is working well and displaying a `JFrame` across two of my monitors with `1920 x 1020` resolutions each,

```
JFrame myFrame=new JFrame("Welcome");
myFrame.setLocation(0, 10);
myFrame.setSize(3830,1020);
myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

But, when i tried to make the `JFrame` undecorated by adding,

```
myFrame.setUndecorated(true);
```

The frame is displaying only in the primary display and nothing is seen in my second screen.

Anyone, please help me in this regard.

Comment: Perhaps method [setExtendedState](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-), in class `java.awt.Frame`, is appropriate? Maybe in combination with method [setMaximizedBounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setMaximizedBounds-java.awt.Rectangle-), also in class `java.awt.Frame`.

Comment: Thank you @Abra, i tried your suggestion but unfortunately there is no change in the behaviour.